# MVC - passar uma variável php para o controller do angular.js

Tags: angularjs, mvc

Eu estou a fazer uma listagem e quero passar os valores de um model para o script algular que está na view.

Model:

```
 function getAllDisplayable_all()
 {
    $this->db->select('id_menu, nome, descricao, preco, foto');
    $result = $this->db->get('menus');
    return $result->result();
 }
```

script:

```
 <script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [ 
         'teste',
        //quero passar as variaveis php para aqui
        ];
    });
</script>
```

listagem html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
             <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                     <th>Nome</th>
                     <th>Preço</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
             <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
                 <td>{{ x }}</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Normalmente eu tenho ido buscar os dados da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $menus): ?>
                      <div class="pr">
                          <?php echo $menus->nome?>
                      </div>
          <?php endforeach ?>
```

Mas desta vez preciso de usar o angular.js. 
Obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso, você precisa fazer uma requisição para obter os dados pois não é possível fazer inserção de `php` diretamente no angular, como é feito em uma view, por exemplo.

Para isso você precisa usar o serviço `$http`, ficando assim:

```
$http.get('sua/url/arquivo.php').then(
    function(response) {
        //Executado com sucesso
        $scope.valor = response.data;
    },
    function(error) {
        //Algo deu errado
        console.info('algo deu errado:', error);
    }
)
```

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('sua/url/arquivo.php').then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data;
        },
        function(error) {
            console.info('algo deu errado:', error);
        }
    )
});
```

Note que você precisa fazer a injeção do serviço em seu `controller`.

---

Respondendo as questões do comentário.

```
//Sim, aqui você coloca o caminho para o arquivo onde está obtendo os dados
$http.get('url/arquivo.php')...
```

É necessário usar `response.data` pois o objeto retornado pelo $http é composto de:

- config
- data
- headers
- statusText

Se você deseja obter apenas os dados, deverá usar `response.data`. Mas com o objeto todo você pode fazer outras verificações, como o status de retorno, se foi 200 ou 404, por exemplo, da seguinte maneira:

```
if(response.status == 404) {
    alert('arquivo não encontrado);
} else if (response.status == 200) {
    $scope.names = response.data;
}
```

São mais opções que temos para fazer um trabalho mais bem elaborado. Para saber mais, recomendo [ler mais sobre o serviço `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Sobre a injeção seria isso aqui: `controller($scope, $http)`, do mesmo modo que você fez com o `$scope`. Apenas comentei para que você soubesse que esta etapa é obrigatória.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54261/discussion-on-answer-by-celsomtrindade-mvc-passar-uma-variavel-php-para-o-cont)

Answer (score 1):

Estava com o mesmo problema, o que eu fiz: passei o conteúdo que tinha dendro da minha variável php em forma de json para variável do angular no teu exemplo, ficaria assim.

```
    <script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.names = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>;
  });
</script>

meu html ficou assim

     <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in names  | filter:pesquisa">
                  <td>{{value.username}} </td>
                  <td>{{value.email}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

Só pra ressaltar, estou usando cakephp3, então a variável $user está vindo do meu controller userController dentro da função lista, onde nela tenho uma variável $usertable onde contem informações de usuário do meu banco e assim seto para a variável $user

```
$this->set('user', $user);
```

Desse jeito.